# Str_getcsv / fgetcsv enclosure doesn't work when line break

Tags: php, parsing, fgetcsv

I have a problem about a csv with line breaks in field, I use libreoffice to enclose fields in a quote ("), and I try to use str_getcsv or fgetcsv but this doesn't work, when it find a line break they create a new line, and doesn't matter of the enclosure.

Here is what I try with str_getcsv :

```
$lines = array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, ",", '"');}, file($full_path));
```

And with fgetcsv

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, PHP_EOL, '"')) !== FALSE) {

    dsm($data);
  }
```

No one works

Here is a example of some values I have in the csv
[image]

EDIT : With "\"" instead of '"' this works, but I have something strange ..

[image]

The 23 value is the one I want, there are some characters but nothing inside, even if I try to get in with php

Csv text content :

```
48725,"RAABE","JEAN JACQUES ET GENEVIEVE","VOEUX 09","15 CLOS DES LILAS",,,57155,"MARLY","FRANCE",0,"C","RAABE JEAN JACQUES ET GENEVIEVE 48725",,"4/22/2000",387633291,387553350,"06 74 86 05 85 : lui 06 89 38 45 23 : elle","genevieveraabe@yahoo.fr",,,,2012,"2012 Cappadoce Lib X 2 
2011 Trièves en Lib X 2 fidélité
2011 Iles anglo-normandes lib x 2
2011 Crète en Lib X 2
E 2010 MERCANTOUR LIB X 2
2010 Balcons de la Cote d'Azur x2 fidélité
2009 DECOUVERTE GR20 LIB x2
2009 Le Cilento et Paestum lib x2
H2009 Iles Canaries (Tenerife) lib x 2
H2008 ENGADINE sdf lib x 2 fidélité
2007 CHYPRE x 2
2007 Corte à Piana lib x 2
2007 corfou lib x 2
E 04 Val anniviers lib X2 fidelité
E 03 DOLO LIB x2
H 91 VERCORS SAUVAGE 
H 02 Arcanson",1990,"agence","atalante",2016,0,1,16,,,,,,,,,,,"03/03/16","CATA H2016","08/02/18",1949,,,1950,,"amarin",1,,0
```

Comment: Done, check the edit

Comment: I add it but now this seem to work but there is something strange, my values are strings and they have caracter but when I try to show them there is nothing inside

Comment: Check the second screen, my values are here but invisible, there is 463 characters that correspond to the value enclosed by the "" but the value is invisible and when I try to use them there is nothing inside

Comment: It's a function of drupal, but with var_dump it's the same I have nothing in the 23 position if there is too much caracters

Comment: I can only assume it has something to do with character encoding. Good luck.

Comment: same for the name, sometimes there is nothing ... this csv is strange